# How to test html page title in AngularJS using karma , jasmine

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine, title

I want to test the html page title as one of my unit cases in angularJS. The name of my controller is 'MainController'. Can i access the title without the scope of the controller.?

describe('Testing Currency App',function(){
    beforeEach(module('currencyConv'));

```
describe('Testing Currency App Controller',function(){

    var scope = {};
    var ctrl;

    beforeEach(inject(function($controller,$rootScope){
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        ctrl = $controller('MainController', {$scope:scope});
        rootScope = $rootScope;
    }));


    it('should initialise the title',function(){
        expect(scope.title).toBeDefined();
        expect(scope.title).toBe('Angular Currency Converter');
    });
});
```

});

I am new at angular

Answer (score 0):

The below link will help you to get your answer ,

`link :` https://medium.com/frontend-fun/angular-unit-testing-jasmine-karma-step-by-step-e3376d110ab4